# Why are parameters in output of my support vector regression going to zero?

Tags: svm, matlab, libsvm

I am trying to predict next value in a time series from epsilon-support vector regression using libsvm library in matlab.Following is my code. From an excel file, I am taking first 3500 samples for training. Based on minimum cross validation mean square error, I want to decide how many lags to consider in order to predict the next value.

```
filename='test.xlsx';
F=xlsread(filename,'B2:B5001');
f_trainx =(1:3500)';  % time instants
f_trainy=F(1:3500);  % observed values
f_testx=(3501:5000)';
f_testy=F(3501:5000);

for d=0:20   %% d= no. of lags considered for prediction  
   [C,gamma,eps] = meshgrid(-10:2:15, -20:2:3 , -20:2:3); 
   svm_ip=f_trainx(end:-1:end-d);
   svm_op=f_trainy(end:-1:end-d);
   s=3;  % for epsilon svr
   t=2;  % for rbf kernel
   folds = 5;
   h=0;
   %p=2^5; % value of epsilon

   for j=1:numel(C)
      mse(j) = svmtrain(svm_op,svm_ip, ...          
      sprintf('-s %d -t %d -c %f -g %f -p %f  -v %d -h %d',s,t, 2^C(j), ... 
      2^gamma(j),2^eps(j), folds ,h));
   end

   [~,idx] = min(mse);
   mse_cv =mse(idx);
   best_C = 2^C(idx);
   best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx) ;
   best_eps = 2^eps(idx);
   options = sprintf(' -s %d -t %d -c %f -g %f ...
                                      -p %f -%d',s,t,2^C(idx),2^gamma(idx),2^eps(idx),h);
   model   = svmtrain(svm_op, svm_ip, options)

   x2 = 3501 ; % first value from test set
   y2 = rand(1); % y2 is to be predicted,so taking any random value for it.
```

but on executing this code, for all iterations, I get the following output on console

```
optimization finished, #iter = 0
nu = 0.000000
obj = 0.000000, rho = -49.125125
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
```

i.e the values of iter,nu,obj,nSV and nBSV are always 0. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The for loop for d has no end

Comment: That is a typo by mistake. In original code, all the loops are properly ended. But the optimization shows no result. Some default values for parameter rho ,mean squared error and squared correlation coefficient are displayed. For # itr,nu,obj,nSV,nBSV , every time, a zero is shown. I am not sure even if the code is properly executing or not.

Comment: Still it would be good to correct that typo. Also, what did you do to debug your code?